# Inheritance in C# from abstract classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, internal

I have a question regarding inheritance in C#. I have a public abstract class A that defines protected virtual members. I have another abstract class B that inherits from A, and then another internal class C, inheriting from B. The first class A is in a separate namespace, and the other two are in the same namespace, but include a reference to the first.

I was trying to access the protected virtual member of A in C using base keyword, but am unable to unless I provide a method in B and then call A's protected virtual member there.

I want to know if what I was trying to do is possible, i.e. was I doing something incorrectly? Or if its not possible, then why? 
Thanks.

Here's the code sample :

```
  namespace A
  {

     public abstract class BaseClass
     {
         protected virtual string GetData()
         {
             //code to get data
         }
     }
  }

  namespace B  //includes a reference to A
  {
     abstract class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
     {

     }


     internal class DerivedClassB: DerivedClassA
     {
          public void write()
          {
             base.GetData(); // results in error.

             // The name 'GetData' does not exist in the current context
             // and DerivedClassA does not contain a definition for 'GetData'
          }
     }
```

Comment: You should include a small code example of what you're trying to do. It would be easier to understand.

Comment: @JoelGauvreau  Since, the hierarchy here was pretty simple, I didn't feel the need to provide a code sample. Its pretty much the same that I 've described.

Comment: What you have described will work just fine.  It could be an error in your code.  We can't know what it is unless we see it.  You said you are "unable to", what does that mean?  You got a compiler or runtime error?  If so, which one?

Comment: @Setafire if you feel that way then your question will be closed as off topic, from the candid close message: "*Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and include **valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.*"

Comment: @TrevorElliott the errors are inline in the code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am sorry that I didn't add code. I have added it now. Please have a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: your sample works fine for me...maybe there is something else that is causing your particular case to fail?

Comment: @JoelGauvreau you mean I should be able to access the GetData in DerivedClassB right? Oh and yes, the two namespaces are in two different solutions. I don't know if that might make a difference.

Comment: @Setafire are you sure `BaseClass` is explicitly marked `public`? If it says nothing at all or `internal` it will not be available in separate solutions. And are you sure `GetData()` is marked `protected`? If it has nothing at all or says `protected internal` it will not be available in separate solutions too. That is why the 2nd C in SSCCE stands for "Complete" so we can recreate the problem on our computers, right now (as you can see from my answer) I can't recreate the problem without adding extra classes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes I am sure the BaseClass is marked public abstract and GetData() is marked protected, and not protected internal or nothing at all. I basically just copy-pasted my code here, and removed the internal working and changed names.

Comment: Well, then I would recommend creating a fully compilable example (except for the compiler error you are having the issue with) and post that in your question instead as there is no errors with the code you have posted now.

Comment: The keyword base refers to which class in your case when your code runs fine? When I look at base, it points to the DerivedClassA for me.

Comment: Wo! People here are so quick in downvoting. I did my research and then posted it here to ask for help. I don't see how clearer it can be further and I do think the inheritance is useful, if not to the downvoter.

Comment: @Setafire I agree, this question was handled a little harshly.  Welcome to the internet I guess.

Comment: @Setafire If you solved it your self you should post your own answer and mark it accepted, otherwise it will keep coming up on the front page as a question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the source of the problem. Apparently, the location of the dlls that the second namespace was referring to had changed and hence, it was pointing to an outdated reference. After I updated the references from the correct location, it ran fine. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Other than a namespace issue [your code ran fine](http://ideone.com/hZ66sX), the one thing I had to change was change `DerivedClassA` to

```
abstract class DerivedClassA : A.BaseClass
{

}
```

What I suspect is whatever `BaseClass` is called in your real project you have a class of the same name in namespace `B` or some other namespace you have included in your `using` statements at the top of your code. For example this would [recreate your error](http://ideone.com/YxrChe)

```
  namespace A
  {

     public abstract class BaseClass
     {
         protected virtual string GetData()
         {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
     }
  }

  namespace B  //includes a reference to A
  {
     public abstract class BaseClass
     {
     }


     abstract class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
     {

     }


     internal class DerivedClassB: DerivedClassA
     {
          public void write()
          {
             base.GetData(); // results in error.

             // The name 'GetData' does not exist in the current context
             // and DerivedClassA does not contain a definition for 'GetData'
          }
     }
  }
```

Check that you don't have another namespace that uses the same name as `BaseClass` or explicitly define the namespace of `BaseClass` in `DerivedClassA`

Comment: I checked, I don't have any other class by the name BaseClass in my second namespace. Also, it shows me the correct class with correct namespace when I hover over the BaseClass name in DerivedClassA's signature. Adding the namespace path before it, too didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the scopes correctly to your example? did you add a `public` or a `protected` where there was none?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Protectedmemberinabstractclassex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
namespace A
{

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual string GetData()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace B  //includes a reference to A
{


    abstract class DerivedClassA : A.BaseClass
    {

    }


    internal class DerivedClassB : DerivedClassA
    {
        public void write()
        {
            base.GetData();
        }
    }
}
```